# spring boot 1.5.1- hibernate second level cache

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache

I am trying to implement hibernate second level cache in spring-boot 1.5.1 . Facing the below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
```

Session cofiguration

```
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
```

JPA POJO

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage= CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region="messageCache")
@Table(name="AWARD")
public class Award {
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="1000" overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="messageCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

Comment: I assume you do have `hibernate-ehcache` on the classpath?

Comment: Yes I have
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache is NOT the ehcache jar. It's the integration jar for Hibernate and ehcache.

Comment: I question how your `hibernateProperties` are being passed because with those configuration settings as I point out below, Spring Boot starts up just fine with EhCache & Hibernate.

Comment: Same issue, it was working on spring boot 1.4.5. Seems break in spring boot 1.5. I was using spring data jpa's default Hiberante v5.0.12.Final.

Answer (score 4):

I just tested this using Spring Boot 1.5.1 and Hibernate 5.2.8 using the following settings in `hibernate.properties` (even specifying the properties when creating the entity manager bean in java config works too)

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true   
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

I setup a simple entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "simpleCache")
public class Simple {
}
```

And specified my `ehcache.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
  <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="1000" overflowToDisk="false"/>
  <cache name="simpleCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

The pom.xml things:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.hibernate.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>stackoverflow</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Spring starts up just fine:

```
INFO 8674 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.8.Final}
INFO 8674 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory, hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
INFO 8674 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
INFO 8674 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
WARN 8674 --- [           main] c.e.i.s.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl : HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [simpleCache]
```

Comment: Naros can you plesae paste your full pom.xml file

Comment: @AmbarishKumarLowsarwar Done, its basically a default `start.sping.io` pom.xml with a few dependencies added to avoid bringing in `spring-data-jpa` as that isn't relevant here.

Comment: Why using hibernate 5.2.8, instead of the default v5.0.12, which was the default of spring data jpa.

Comment: Perhaps there is a feature or bugfix the user is interested it that only exists in 5.2.x given that is the current community branch.

Answer (score 1):

It is **NOT** a classpath issue. It is a missing hibernate configuration. So basically, your session configuration is not reaching hibernate.

I can't tell why because I don't know how hibernate was initialized. I can show you a working Spring-boot implementation though. With Ehcache 3.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/system/CacheConfiguration.java

and a fully configured cache in JHipster:
https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sample/config/CacheConfiguration.java

Comment: broken link , the first one , any chances you have it still ?

Comment: I've fixed the links

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ehcache jar to your class path. The one you listed in the comment above is not the ehcache jar.

This is what you need to add:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.3

Comment: It too does not help

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

Had same issue, appending your property with this **spring.jpa.properties** is important if you are using Spring JPA.