# Hibernate configuration - NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

Im getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
```

But i have that property set:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Im Using Hibernate 4.3.10.Final and i have all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with SpringBoot and Hibernate. There was some issue with the versions. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457760/spring-boot-1-5-1-hibernate-second-level-cache) helped me.

I used `Spring Boot 1.5.1` and `Hibernate 5.2.8` and modified hibernate.properties file as below:

```
 hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true   
 hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

Add caching annotations on the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Test{
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17983345)

Comment: Thanks @EJoshuaS , i modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put an exception breakpoint on `NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException` and check what is missing. This error rings a bell but I don't remember the exact cause. But that's how I debugged it.

Are you using Ehcache 3? Because the current provider is for Ehcache 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I changed the version of hibernate in pom.xml

If you have the same error for old applications you can change the version and solved it.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```